# What are the limits for channels and supergroups?

Tags: telegram

I've received the following message when joining another channel:

> Sorry, you have joined too many channels and supergroups. Please leave some before joining this one.

I'm not sure on how many groups/channels I'm at, but I guess on a lot, and I wasn't aware of the limit.

Can somebody explains what's the limit exactly? Does it include private groups as well? Can this limit be increased somehow?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Kyle2142's comment](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/4883):

> Telegram has a limit of 500 supergroups per account.

This is the limit of Telegram API, not the client.

The private group doesn't count, as I can still create a new one, despite of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

You are limited to 50 channels maximum. If you want to have more, you can use special tricks. For example, you can use this bot which allows you to join different channels into one feed so you can read them like one channel. And you do not need to join these channels by yourself.

- **https://t.me/junction_bot**

Comment: 500 channels and supergroups. not 50.